# Entity Framework : Single model constructed by multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model layer which is consisting of multiple classes and each class needs to get data from a different database. How can I manage this and also how can I change connection string in the repository layer:

```
public class MapRepository : EFRepository<Map>, IMapRepository
    {

        public MapRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {
            context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ""; // is this possible?!!!!
        }
        public IQueryable<Map> GetByMapId(Guid id)
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable().Where(bd => bd.MapId == id);
        }

        public IQueryable<Map> GetByMapCode(string code)
        {
            return DbSet
                .Include("MapIndexes")
                .Include("MapIndexes.MapPages")
                .AsQueryable().Where(bd => bd.MapCode == code);
        }

        public int GetMapsCount()
        {
            return DbSet.Count();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I have solved this problem myself by having one database to rule them all - it contains views (for Entity Framework to bind to) and synonyms to the other databases (a sleight of hand). It works and you can do cross database (and cross server!) joins but ... it's not worth it.

Comment: Anyway, `DbContext` has a constructor that lets you change the connection string between `DbContext` instances. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

Comment: I propose that use multiple contexts in your application.

Comment: What is the advantage of having extra DbContext?